# Python/Django: How to show both main model and 'foreign-key model' together in HTML

Tags: python, django

Good Day SO, I am a beginner in Django and python, just started learning two days ago. Currently, I am trying to do my filtering of data in views.py and creating a context to be shown in my main page that contains both the initial model and the 'foreign-key' model. However, I am having trouble finding help online, even though this is a simple question.. Here goes..

Models involved:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    plan_ID = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=8,
        validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\w{8}$', message='Length has to be 8', code='nomatch')]
    )
    plan_crisisID = models.ForeignKey(Crisis, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    plan_status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Crisis(models.Model):
    crisis_ID = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=4,
        validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\w{4}$', message='Length has to be 4', code='nomatch')]
    )
    crisis_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Views.py for HTML:

```
def home(request):
    template = loader.get_template('pmoapp/home.html')
    crisisList = Crisis.objects.filter(crisis_status='Ongoing').order_by('-crisis_ID')

    context = {
        'crisisList': crisisList,
        #'planList': planList
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And finally, my HTML page:

```
<tbody>
    {% if crisisList %}
         {% for crisis in crisisList %}
              <tr>
                   <td>{{ crisis.crisis_ID }}</td>
                   <td><a href="/report/{{ crisis.crisis_ID}}">{{ crisis.crisis_name }}</a></td>
                   <td>{{ crisis.crisis_dateTime }}</td>
                   <td>planid</td>
                   <td>planstatus</td>
             </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
          <p>No crisis available.</p>
      {% endif %}
 </tbody>
```

I have several things that I do not know how to do here.. so sorry and bear with me..

As seen above, I am currently only able to show the attributes of the Crisis model, and I do not know how to show the Plan, nor how to filter the data to get the plan with the same crisis ID and highest plan ID

I have a many-to-one relationship between Crisis and Plan, such that a Crisis can have multiple plans, linked by *'Foreign-key': plan_crisisID*. I would like for the HTML to show all Crisis objects, and the plan with the *highest id value and belonging to the same crisis* in the HTML format seen above (*planid, planstatus*).

I know that the logic portion of this code is done in views.py, however I do not know how to start, or what to do.. Thank you SO for your kind help, I will provide any additional information required.. I have many other similar models with foreign key and many-to-many links and in similar situations.. I hope to learn from answers here so that I can replicate this in other places in my project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are on the right track, but should start from the other end because Crisis is on Plan.

In the views pull planlist instead of crisislist, then you can:

```
<tbody>
{% if planList %}
     {% for plan in planList %}
          <tr>
               <td>{{ plan.crisisID.crisis_ID }}</td>
               <td><a href="/report/{{ panel.crisisID.crisis_ID}}">{{ crisis.crisis_name }}</a></td>
               <td>{{ plan.crisisID.crisis_dateTime }}</td>
               <td>{{ plan.plan_ID }}</td>
               <td>{{ plan.planstatus }}</td>
         </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      <p>No crisis available.</p>
  {% endif %}
</tbody>
```

Oh and you should probably swap the query to something like:

```
planList = Plan.objects.filter(crisis_ID__crisis_status='Ongoing').order_by('-crisisID__crisis_ID')
```

Comment: Yes! I realised that after i posted the question. Initially I used Crisis first because.. I do not know how to look for the Plan with the highest Plan ID and how to code it via python in views.py. I know how to do it in other languages, but I currently do not know how to do it in views.py via python.. Edit: Also, because I have a filter on my Crisis status = 'Ongoing', I also do not know how to filter for this information in the planList as well.. sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: you just read my mind! Can I run a for-loop in the views.py to get the maximum value for my Plan ID? or do i import a math module to get a max() method?

Comment: There is an error Edit: tried using this instead: planList = Plan.objects.filter(plan_crisisID__crisis_status='Ongoing')

Comment: Good catch, the orderby is from the Crisis object.

Comment: Learning new things everyday, thanks to awesome people like you bro :) Have a nice day!